# API Gateway Javascript SDK - Node Js Examples?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

So The API Gateway Javascript SDK is great to use in the front-end environment, but since the 10+ script files are required to be available globally, this does not play very nicely in an environment where most developers are used to importing npm packages.

Is there an example of anyone using the API Gateway SDK in backend Node.js environment? Here you cannot put the 10+ scripts in index.html file and I keep getting errors and when I try to make these files globally available for the SDK in Node environment.

Comment: You might want to take a look this NPM package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-api-gateway-client

Comment: [AWS SDK for JavaScript in Node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/)

Answer (score -3):

There are two AWS SDKs for JavaScript.  Use the one for [node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) linked in the comment from MaiKaY.  And here is the reference for the API Gateway portion of the SDK - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html